# asp.net mvc .ajax error catching

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax

I'm having some issues catching error messages from a controller via .ajax error. The script is called by a jQuery UI Dialog popup. Any help would be appreciated.

Here's the code snippet from my controller

```
            Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
            return Content("There was an error in your request.", MediaTypeNames.Text.Plain);
```

and here's the jQuery script:

```
function submitFormWithAjax(form) {
    form = $(form);
    $.ajax({
        url: form.attr('action'),
        data: form.serialize(),
        type: (form.attr('method')),
        dataType: 'text',
        error: function(data) {
            $('#result').html(data);
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $('#result').html(data);
            setTimeout("reloadPage()", 500);
        }
    });
  return false;
}
```

The `error: function(data)` isn't reading the returned error message. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for everyone's help. I figured it out after some trial, all I needed to do was this in jQuery

```
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, exceptionThrown) {
        $('#result').html(xhr.responseText);
    },
```

and this in the controller

```
            Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
            return Content("There was an error in your request.");
```

Comment: Problem with this is if there in an exception during processing, the full error page html will be dumped into your result div.

Answer (score 1):

The signature for the error callback is `function(xmlHttpRequest, textStatus, exceptionThrown)`.

Maybe you're looking at the wrong parameter?

Comment: Thanks, I changed the code to error: function(xmlHttpRequest, textStatus, exceptionThrown) and I can access xmlHttepRequest. However, how do I attach my error message in the controller? I guess return Content("There was an error in your request.", MediaTypeNames.Text.Plain); isn't right.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with ASP.NET MVC, but my guess is you have to return a View. That's all I can offer thus far.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    function submitFormWithAjax(form) {
    form = $(form);
    $.ajax({
        url: form.attr('action'),
        data: form.serialize(),
        type: (form.attr('method')),
        dataType: 'text',
        error: function(data) {
            $('#result').html(data);
        },
        success: function(xmlHttpRequest, textStatus, exceptionThrown) {
            $('#result').html(xmlHttpRequest.statusText);
            setTimeout("reloadPage()", 500);
        }
    });
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It must be something about returning a BadRequest (error 400.) The error callback does seem to be called when the return code is Conflic (error 409).